# Re-run the current function when the function is a variable

Tags: function, go

I have a function named `test` which is inside the main func.

```
//stuff

func main() {
  var test = func() {
    if (/*some condition from main*/) {
      return test()
    }
  }

  val := test()
}
```

When i run this it says:

> undefined: test

and it is referencing the `return test()` inside the test func.
How can i fix this?

Comment: `var test func(); test = func() { ... }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to declare the variable before you use it:

```
var test func()
test=func() {
   if ... {
     test()
   }
}
```